# Contradiction in scripture about karma

Tags: karma, explanation, contradiction

So, we face results of good and bad deeds done by us. But do we also face karma of others like ruler is foolish or a doctor may be idiot. So, I think we don't face karma only of our own.

But even scriptures don't agree on this topic (with single opinion)

> Mahabharata - Shanti Parva - Moksha Dhama Parva -Chapter 291
>
> नायं परस्य सुकृतं दुष्कृतं चापि सेवते ।
>
> करोति यादृशं कर्मं तादृशं प्रतिपद्यते
>
> One never has to enjoy or endure the good and bad acts of another.
> Indeed, one enjoys and endures the fruits of only those acts that one
> does oneself
>
> Brahmasutra 3.2.38 “The fruit (arises) from this, on account of
> appropriateness.”

> Mantridoshascha rAjAnam jAyAdoshah patim yathA | TathA
> prApnotyasandeham shishyapApam gurum priye ||
>
> Just like a king gets affected by the sins committed by his ministers,
> a husband gets affected by the sins committed by his wife, likewise,
> without any doubt, O Beloved, a disciple's sins affect the Teacher
> (Guru). [KulArnava Tantram 11.110]

Main question is just that

***Do I face  karma of others or not?
How can the lines of both mahabharat and tantra text be true?Explain***

Comment: Not sure what your question is. There are no contradictions between the quotes you gave.

Comment: Very good question.

Comment: The quote from Kularnava Tantra is from chapter 7.

Comment: In the context of Advaita, there are different forms of Prarabdha Karmas - without desire, other's desire that MUST exist till full liberation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prarabdha_karma#:~:text=Kinds%20of%20Prarabdha%20Karma%5B,has%20to%20undergo.%5B4%5D

The solution in terms of Advaita is given by Ramana Maharshi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prarabdha_karma#:~:text=Sage%20Ramana%20Maharshi,actions.%5B10%5D

Answer (score 1):

The English translation is not accurate.

A better translation is:

> Just as the sins of the ministers are laid at the door of the king, of
> the wife at the husband’s, so do the sins of the disciple accrue to
> the Guru.

**Kularnava Tantra, Worship, Readings by M.P. Pandit**

What it is saying is that a Guru has to take the sins of the disciple willingly. He is taking the responsibility for the spiritual progress of his disciple and has to take his sins also. This is an exceptional case. The comparison with the two cases of people blaming the king for the misdeeds of his minister and blaming the husband for the misdeed of the wife is certainly confusing.

People who are not Gurus don't have to take the bad karma of others.